# Exclusive OR of Ruby Sets - Determining which set each element came from

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to determine which set an element came from when you perform an exclusive or operation on 2 sets in Ruby.

```
require 'set'

set_a = [1,2,3].to_set
set_b = [2,3,4].to_set

set_a ^ set_b # => returns a new set containing elements [4,1]
```

But what I would need is something like this

```
require 'set'

set_a = [1,2,3].to_set
set_b = [2,3,4].to_set

set_a ^ set_b # => should return something like [set_b(4), set_a(1)]
```

Comment: Why not just use `set_b.include?(4)`?

Comment: There is nothing like this built-in to Ruby. You'll have to write a simple bit of code to do this.

Comment: I've provided an answer that will work for any number of sets. The return type can be modified though. In my answer it's a hash with element keys and set values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. But you could return a hash with element keys and set values.

```
def pick_a_name( *sets )
  sets.reduce(:^).each_with_object({}) do |element, hash|
    hash[element] = sets.find{ |set| set.include?(element) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not something simple as this?

```
require 'set'

set_a = [1,2,3].to_set
set_b = [2,3,4].to_set

in_a = set_a - set_b # #<Set: {1}>
in_b = set_b - set_a # #<Set: {4}>

# make any structure you like from in_a and in_b
```

(This does not answer the question directly because the exlusive or / `^` hat is not used but I hope it is still okey)

Comment: I am looking for a solution which can work for any number of sets, (5 sets, 10 sets, 100000 sets). I probably should have pointed that out, but I assumed there would be a "ruby way" which would account for x number of sets, by default.

Comment: You mean something like `set_a ^ set_b ^ set_c ^ set_d ^ ...`?

Comment: But then I am not totally sure what you want to get, for example what should be the output used with `set_a = [1,2,3]`, `set_b = [2,3,4]` and `set_c = [1, 2]` - should it return that `2` is in `set_a`, `set_b` and `set_c`? (because `set_a ^ set_b ^ set_c = [2]`)? Is this really what you want?

Comment: Aha, I see your point.  What I would need is set_a = [1,2,3], set_b = [2,3,4], set_c = [1,2,5], new_set = [set_a(1),set_b(4),set_c(5)]

Comment: Why `set_a(1)`? I am confused O.o (`[1,2,3].to_set ^ [2,3,4].to_set ^ [1,2,5].to_set = #<Set: {2, 5, 4}>`).